# group_concat not showing me what I expect

Tags: mysql

I actually know why group_concat isn't showing me what I need but I'd like to know how I can get it to work.

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT e.name)
```

This is the code I am am using. This will concat all of the people's names within a particular department. The issue is, when I have two or more people a given department with the same name, I am only shown one of them.

Do I need a sub query for this to show me all of the names? Can someone show me what I need or point me to a query that may help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't use `DISTINCT`

```
GROUP_CONCAT(e.name)
```

Comment: Well... I sort of need that. :)  If I forgo `DISTINCT` then I will get duplicate names, one for each row in the data set

Comment: Well then show your exact table schema, sample data, desired output and your current query. Otherwise we can guess indefinitely

Comment: OK, Peterm, I'll put it together and post up top. Thanks for the answer, I appreciate the help

Comment: Thanks Peter, I got it and I did have to remove `DISTINCT` in addition to a couple of other things.